# Phonegap app - alternatives to Pusher and PubNub

Tags: javascript, cordova, websocket, pusher, pubnub

I'm building a phonegap app and one aspect of the app involves chat rooms and allowing users to broadcast 160 character long messages to all other users within the chat rooms. I dont mind if these messages are broadcast to all users immediately or require each user to do a "pull-to-refresh" before seeing any new messages.

One major issue is that my app is sports event based and requests will go from almost none during midweek to thousands during a football game. I have looked at Pusher and PubNub and their services seem very expensive and unsuited as they look at peak connections. Pubnub, which I have currently implemented, charge $49 for just 500 peak connections. I expect many more than that during a football game, but very few 95% of the time.

What are the alternatives for me? Keep in mind I don't want to spend months coding a service myself as this isn't the core of the app. I would like to use an open source solution or something cheaper and more suited to my needs than Pusher or PubNub

Comment: Good news -- PubNub is moving to a simplified billing model that no longer uses Peak Connections!

Comment: Also call PubNub directly and we can help/assist with the new billing models that fit your needs. - support at pubnub.com - http://www.pubnub.com/about-us

Comment: Thank you, I will be in touch as I really like PubNubs simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a bit late, but you can check http://beebotte.com for your need. Beebotte does not apply connection limitations.

This tutorial for realtime chat application may be useful:
http://beebotte.com/tutorials/chat

Answer (score 0):

To address the cost in your question - [PubNub has new pricing plans](https://www.pubnub.com/pricing/) with up to **100 daily active devices** on the **FREE** tier and **Access Manager** is **FREE** for all accounts.